# Input fields not applying bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My input fields are not applying the bootstrap styles but my dropdown does. My code is below. I am using the partial view here.

```
@model SMC_AMS.Models.ViewModel.UserSignUpView

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<h1 class="page-header">Registration</h1>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Signup</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
                         {
                             new SelectListItem {Text = "Male", Value = "M"},
                             new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "F"}
                         }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to Main", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You want to discuss what is primarily a client-side problem here - so please show client-side code, and not server-side code that almost no one here will be able to run to try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: What do you mean? That is the code on the page that I am having issue. I think that is the page the client will be seeing.

Comment: No, that looks like some server-side MVC template code ...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody wants to know, I just changed the "EditorFor" to "TextboxFor"

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName)
                </div>
            </div>
```